# Is there a mathematical formula to solve for recursively dependent Bernoulli trials? (Given a simple example scenario below)

Tags: probability, integration, limits, probability-theory, statistics

I think this is the easiest way to phrase my question. For example you have N coins. You flip each coin until it shows up as heads. What would be the formula to calculate the average # of flips you have to do before they are all heads?

As you could get an indefinite number of tails, I think you would calculate some limit of probabilities of some sort.

Comment: You mean coin A is tossed again and again until it shows heads, then it is put aside and coin B is tossed and so on ? Can you clarify, and also tell what difficulty you are facing.

Comment: @trueblueanil yes say you have like 10 coins you would flip each of them until they are all heads. If it lands tails then you flip again.

Comment: If they are tossed one by one until they show heads, and then you move on to the next coin, the experiment is not "recursively dependent.."

Comment: Yep you are right thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single coin with probability $p$ of landing on heads, it will take on average $\frac 1p$ tosses to land on heads if we keep repeating the tosses until it does.  This is a standard result from the geometric distribution.  Now for $N$ coins, the average total number of tosses is just $\frac Np$ because taking the average is additive, i.e. it's the average tosses needed for coin 1 + average tosses needed for coin 2 + ... + average tosses needed for coin $N$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!